How can I update/add an entity reference field on content A with content B when content A field ID is equal to content B field ID?
I have two content types, Content A and Content B, which both have a field_code field.
Content A has an entity reference type field (field_content) whose settings are reference type (Content) and vontent type (content_b).
I want to populate Content A's field_content with Content B's field_content when Content A and Content B's field_code have an exact match.
I can do this in the UI by searching for field_code which is part of Content B's title.
As I have more than 500 content items to do I would like to do this automatically, I have looked at doing is via a custom module, node_presave, migrate yaml files and a preprocess function in my custom theme.
Note: Content B has been generate by a migrate YAML file.

node_presave() can do this in a custom module. Write the code to do the update and then just re-save all the content and it should be updated correctly.
